# Google Play Store publish for lower android versions(API)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

My App is available and was accepted. It is only available for new android versions (API level 30). Is there a way after the recent change in November 2021. Is there a way to publish for older versions (API level 28). The big companies like supercell or Voodoo Games still publish for older versions. Do they have special privileges or how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` values.

The `minSdkVersion` dictates the lowest version of android your app supports. You can ship an app with the latest `targetSdkVersion` and still support your app on older devices.

Check out the documentation:  [Android SDK version properties](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/sdk-versions)

Comment: ok thats strange. Thats how I understood it at the beginning. I send my app for approval with minSDK 29 and Target 31. It got rejected so I just changed the API to min 30 and target 30 and it worked.